# how to unstall xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2

I'm using this command to unstall xocode 4.2 "sudo ./Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all"  then the error appears

ERROR: Xcode appears to be running.  You must first quit the following programs before the uninstaller can proceed:
1960   ??  S      0:00.14 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/backgroundinstruments.app/Contents/MacOS/backgroundinstruments
2148   ??  S      0:01.35 /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn_0_577677
2303 s000  R+     0:00.01 /usr/bin/perl ./Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

any one has some ideas?

Comment: I found the answer my self   <br /> Be sure in the root fold 
`./Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`
you must run with root permission

Answer (score 2):

I found that iTunes also caused `backgroundinstruments` to be in use. quit XCode and iTunes then try to uninstall.